# Draw arrow on line algorithm

Tags: algorithm, drawing, line

Does anyone have an algorithm for drawing an arrow in the middle of a given line. I have searched for google but haven't found any good implementation.

P.S. I really don't mind the language, but it would be great if it was Java, since it is the language I am using for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this an arrow pointing at the middle of a line?  Or coming from it?  Or an arrowhead that runs along the line?

Comment: one that runs along the line.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here's a function to draw an arrow with its head at a point p. You would set this to the midpoint of your line. dx and dy are the line direction, which is given by (x1 - x0, y1 - y0). This will give an arrow that is scaled to the line length. Normalize this direction if you want the arrow to always be the same size.

```
private static void DrawArrow(Graphics g, Pen pen, Point p, float dx, float dy)
{
    const double cos = 0.866;
    const double sin = 0.500;
    PointF end1 = new PointF(
        (float)(p.X + (dx * cos + dy * -sin)),
        (float)(p.Y + (dx * sin + dy * cos)));
    PointF end2 = new PointF(
        (float)(p.X + (dx * cos + dy * sin)),
        (float)(p.Y + (dx * -sin + dy * cos)));
    g.DrawLine(pen, p, end1);
    g.DrawLine(pen, p, end2);
}
```

Comment: How would one adjust the size of the arrowhead? I like having it based on the length of the line, but the current ratio of arrowhead size to line size is incorrect for my application.

Answer (score 14):

Here's a method to add an arrow head to a line.
You just have to give it the coordinates of your arrow tip and tail.

```
private static void drawArrow(int tipX, int tailX, int tipY, int tailY, Graphics2D g)
{
    int arrowLength = 7; //can be adjusted
    int dx = tipX - tailX;
    int dy = tipY - tailY;

    double theta = Math.atan2(dy, dx);

    double rad = Math.toRadians(35); //35 angle, can be adjusted
    double x = tipX - arrowLength * Math.cos(theta + rad);
    double y = tipY - arrowLength * Math.sin(theta + rad);

    double phi2 = Math.toRadians(-35);//-35 angle, can be adjusted
    double x2 = tipX - arrowLength * Math.cos(theta + phi2);
    double y2 = tipY - arrowLength * Math.sin(theta + phi2);

    int[] arrowYs = new int[3];
    arrowYs[0] = tipY;
    arrowYs[1] = (int) y;
    arrowYs[2] = (int) y2;

    int[] arrowXs = new int[3];
    arrowXs[0] = tipX;
    arrowXs[1] = (int) x;
    arrowXs[2] = (int) x2;

    g.fillPolygon(arrowXs, arrowYs, 3);
}
```